# does default case MUST be included in switch statements in Java

Tags: java, switch-statement, default

I was just wondering if default case MUST be included in switch statements in Java. I understand it is good practice to include default cases. The reason why I ask is because for the code below, if I delete default case, the code will provide error. Could someone please help me clarify the concept? Thanks in advance for any help!

```
public class SwitchDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int month = 8;
        String monthString;
        switch (month) {
            case 1:  monthString = "January";
                     break;
            case 2:  monthString = "February";
                     break;
            case 3:  monthString = "March";
                     break;
            case 4:  monthString = "April";
                     break;
            case 5:  monthString = "May";
                     break;
            case 6:  monthString = "June";
                     break;
            case 7:  monthString = "July";
                     break;
            case 8:  monthString = "August";
                     break;
            case 9:  monthString = "September";
                     break;
            case 10: monthString = "October";
                     break;
            case 11: monthString = "November";
                     break;
            case 12: monthString = "December";
                     break;
            default: monthString = "Invalid month"; //if delete will produce error
                     break;
        }
        System.out.println(monthString);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

While the `default` clause is not mandatory, if you remove it, `monthString` may not be initialized, so you get a compilation error when you attempt to print it with `System.out.println(monthString);`.

You can remove the `default` clause if you give `monthString` a default value when you declare it. For example :

```
String monthString = "Invalid month";
```

This will give the same behavior as your current switch statement, which includes the default clause.

Comment: it is a good practice to initialize the variable on the time of declaration with default value before using it to avoid the above condition. Nice explanation Eran

Comment: @Victor I disagree. Definite assignment is there to ensure that all of your code paths assign the value you intend to assign. It is better to assign the value you intend to assign just once; assigning a value immediately (and maybe overwriting it) takes away one layer of compiler checking of the correctness of your code.

Answer (score 1):

It is not required to have a `default` case, but it is a good idea to have one, since this catches cases that you intentionally do not want to handle (or unintentionally *didn't* handle).

As a point of reference, the [Google Java style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s4.8.4.3-switch-default) requires a `default` case.

In your code, assuming you are free of the strictures of a particular style rule requiring a `default` case, you don't need it; you just need to *definitely assign* `monthString` before you can use it (a requirement in the language specification). However, it doesn't make sense to assign a value for a month value outside the range 1-12 - it is logically wrong.

Throwing an exception is a sensible thing to do here, e.g.:

```
default:
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid month");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you looks your program you will find your error by own because of **Initialization** error.

Here

```
 int month = 8;
 String monthString; //it is a local Variable and not Initialized.
```

`monthString` is not initialized at the time of declaration and this `Variable` doesn't have **global access** (not a global Variable) so that it can initialize using any Constructor or any other source.

In your `switch` statement in all your `case` you have initialize the variable `monthString`. If you consider each `case` and `default` as a differen branch then you will realize that in all possible branch this `code` is getting executed. In each possibility variable `monthString` is initialized but If you Remove this code

```
default: monthString = "Invalid month"; //if delete will produce error
                     break;
```

then there may be a possibility of a `default` case (**if all cases are getting Failed**). So, Indirectly you are not consider this default `case` but there is a possibility of that.

If you still want to remove `default` case then Initialize your variable `monthString` at the time of declaration. It will also remove your Compile time error.

> This is the reason of getting error after removing the `default` keyword.

Thank you